# How to create dll of Lua Module

Tags: c, lua

I'm trying to write an external Lua module.

I work on Windows 8.1 and I use gcc as compiler.

My requirement is to build/compile everything all by myself without using pre-compiled files available online.

First of all, I build C source code of Lua 5.2.4 as follow:

1. gcc -c *.c
2. ren lua.o lua.obj
3. ren luac.o luac.obj
4. ar rcs luaX.X.X.lib *.o
5. gcc -shared -o luaX.X.X.dll *.o
6. gcc lua.c luaX.X.X.lib -o luaX.X.X.exe
7. gcc luac.c luaX.X.X.lib -o luacX.X.X.exe
8. del *.o *.obj

where `X.X.X` is the source code revision.

Once I created my .exe, I write the C code of my module (let's call it LuaMath):

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<math.h>
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lua.h"


static int IdentityMatrix(lua_State *L)
{
    int in = lua_gettop(L);
    if (in!=1)
    {
       lua_pushstring(L,"Maximum 1 argument");
       lua_error(L);
    }
    lua_Number n = lua_tonumber(L,1);
    lua_newtable(L);                  /*                 tabOUT n */
    int i,j;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        lua_newtable(L);              /*         row(i) tabOUT n */
        lua_pushnumber(L,i);          /*       i row(i) tabOUT n */
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            lua_pushnumber(L,j);      /*     j i row(i) tabOUT n */
            if (j==i)
            {
                lua_pushnumber(L,1);
            }
            else                      /* 0/1 j i row(i) tabOUT n */
            {
                lua_pushnumber(L,0);
            }
            /*  Put 0/1 inside row(i) at j position */
            lua_settable(L,-4);       /*       i row(i) tabOUT n */
        }
        lua_insert(L,-2);             /*       row(i) i tabOUT n */

        /* Insert row(i) into position in tabOUT */
        lua_settable(L,2);            /*                tabOUT n */
    }
    return 1;
}


static const struct luaL_Reg LuaMath [] = {{"IdentityMatrix", IdentityMatrix},
                                           {            NULL,           NULL}};

int __declspec(dllexport) luaopen_LuaMath(lua_State *L)
{
    luaL_newlib(L,LuaMath);
    return 1;
}
```

then I compile it linking to dynamic library.dll as follow:

```
gcc -shared -L "<path where luaX.X.X.dll is>" -l "luaX.X.X" LuaMath.c
```

When I call the the module into Lua code as follow:

```
require("LuaMath")
```

the output is:

```
> require("LuaMath")
multiple Lua VMs detected
stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
>
```

What do I do wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited because I removed the initial problem, but now it has another problem. It seems that Lua can't find the Module I write.

Comment: **This is toxic!** Please don't make such significant changes to questions; it makes previously outstanding answers invalid, renders that effort expended to answer the question invalid for future visitors and possibly projects negative votes upon them. **If you have a different question to ask, ask it as a *DIFFERENT QUESTION*!**

Comment: Can I change the question title?

Comment: Yes you can, as long as you narrow down on the issue. And since you have already put most of your rep as a bounty, definitely go ahead, as long as it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not link the Lua library with your DLL. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: You mean "gcc -shared LuaMath.c". If so, it tells me that all Lua C API function are not defined.

Comment: The read me states:Moreover, to dynamically load C libraries for Lua you'll need to know how to create dynamic libraries and you'll need to make sure that the Lua API functions are accessible to those dynamic libraries — but don't link the Lua library into each dynamic library. For Unix, we recommend that the Lua library be linked statically into the host program and its symbols exported for dynamic linking; src/Makefile does this for the Lua interpreter. For Windows, we recommend that the Lua library be a DLL. In all cases, the compiler luac should be linked statically.

Comment: Precisely. It says *"... don't link the Lua library into each dynamic library..."*, which is what you're doing wrong in (both of) your question/s. *"... we recommend that the Lua library be linked statically into the host program ..."* and *not "... into each dynamic library..."*. Do you understand? Link the Lua library *statically* to the *host program* (i.e. the same program that loads the DLL you're trying to build). That's the way I've interpreted this...

Comment: I removed the multiple VM problem, but now Lua can't find the module I write

Comment: Paths for loading shared objects are controlled by [CPATH](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/luaconf.h#L196) or [package.cpath](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.cpath) So, consider putting shared object on the same directory as Your Lua script or.... tinker with `package.cpath` variable accordingly.

Comment: If I keep them into the same folder, it is no necessary to put the dll into CPATH, right?

Comment: Everything is in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need define a SYSCFLAGS `LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL` then compile the lua code again

```
gcc -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL -c *.c
```

Why not you use the Makefile which provide by Lua source? It is easy way to complie, if you read the Makefile， it set the gcc flags for you.

```
cd /path/to/lua-src
make mingw
```

now you should get lua.exe, luac.exe, lua53.dll in /path/to/lua-src/src/

compile your module

```
gcc -shared -I/path/to/lua-src/src LuaMath.c -o LuaMath.dll -L/path/to/lua-src/src -llua53
```

Comment: Linking with -llua53 will give duplicate VMs.